# Refresh view in Rails 3.2 without JavaScript or AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller, refresh

How do I update a view without Javascript/AJAX so that it will call a method in my model in Rails 3.2?

Tweets model:

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.get_tweets
    #get more tweets code and store in DB
  end
end
```

Tweets controller:

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @all_tweets = Tweet.all
  end
end
```

How do I call the get_tweets function via a button or link in the index view? I don't want the page to refresh every time, only when I click on the Refresh link/button.

Thanks

Comment: without using javascript, your only option is to reload the entire page.

Comment: @choise, how do I call the get_tweets function? none of the answers show how to actually do it in Rails, that's my question. What does the view look like? What does the controller look like?

Comment: simply do `Tweet.get_tweets` in your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a route to your routes.rb

`get "Tweets/update_tweet"`

then add a action to your `TweetsController`

```
def update_tweet
 Tweet.get_tweets
 redirect_to :action => "index"
end
```

and in your view add a link to the new route

`<%= link_to "Update Tweets", "/Tweets/update_tweet"%>`

When you click on the link it will trigger the update_tweet action, which will update your database and redirect to your index action which will display the updated tweets.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't/don't want to use JavaScript to refresh a portion of the page, you have to reload the entire page. You can do this every few seconds via a meta tag:

```
<!-- refresh every 30 seconds -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

or create a link to the page:

```
<a href="...">Refresh Tweets</a>
```

or create a form:

```
<form action="..." method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Refresh Tweets">
</form>
```

If none of these are suitable, you could embed an `<iframe>` element in your page and just refresh that document on demand.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Javascript for loading data, but your users have enabled Javascript in their browsers, just create a link or button like this:

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.reload()">Reload Page</a>
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```

Comment: How will this trigger the get_tweets method?

Comment: By calling this method in your view.